# Is theree any way to watch stream using headless puppeteer NodeJS

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to make a bot that will work in nodeys via puppeteer to insert a bot on the trovo.live site that will screenshot my screen every 30 seconds and save that image, I made it to take pictures and save but for some reason the picture of my gameplay doesn't show on screenshot, everything is just black and I can't find anywhere how to solve that problem. This is a  tag

There is screenshot how it looks like https://ibb.co/xhnvQrg